# zsh: Make getting the value of a variable invoke a function

Tags: zsh, function, variable-substitution

I like to use a "getter" function for some variable `foo`, such that using `"$foo"` is equivalent to `"$(foo-getter)"`.

It think this should be possible, as `$EPOCHREALTIME` seems to do so.

Comment: This is not possible with zsh code. `EPOCHREALTIME` is provided by a [module](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html) written in C.

Comment: The implementation can be seen here: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/Modules/datetime.c#L252 It doesn't too hard to implement some custom module (not that I checked how they need to be installed and loaded)

Comment: See also [Prevent command substitution from running when declaring a variable](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/640695) or [What shells support "value substitution" like MirBSD Korn Shell?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/611364) for different avenues

Comment: [Discipline functions](http://www.mtxia.com/js/Downloads/Scripts/Korn/discipline.shtml) are yet another reason to use ksh.